# How to identify all selected features

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, select

At the moment I have selected numerous vectors in a layer using the Select By tool, but what I want to do now is go to the attribute table and only find the selected features that would be highlighted to be grouped together for ease of use. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open the attribute table of the layer with the selected features you're interested in, click on Show All Features in the lower left corner, then Show Selected Features.

[image]